LunarVIM/Neovim create new filtetype and syntax
In LunarVIM config, what I would like is to create a new ftplugin named log with it's associated syntax.
I'd like to have the filetype and syntax within a custom folder (~/.lvim) under source control that it loaded by the default config.lua.
Actually I have:
~/.config/lvim/config.lua
local custom_path = vim.env.HOME .. "/.lvim/?.lua"
package.path = package.path .. ";" .. custom_path
require(custom-config)

~/.lvim/custom-config.lua
require(xxxx) -- same folder xxxx.lua 
require(yyyy) -- same folder yyyy.lua 

This is an example of the log file content (it's logs so nothing really fancy):
[I] [TAG]   This is an info level log
[T] [TAG_2] This is a trace level log
[E] [TAG]   I think you figured this one out!

I have tried to create just a basic syntax file named log.vim like this to easily see that it has been loaded:
if exists("b:current_syntax")
  finish
endif

echom "Log syntax file loaded"

syn match line '^.*$'

highlight line ctermfg=red

let b:current_syntax = "log"

Right now it does not automatically detect all log files (code will be added towards that with also specific ftplugin) but I manually set filetype=log` when I open such file.
If I am here, it is that, of course, my log.vim is never loaded (messages never shows my echom).
I have tried to source ~/.lvim/log.vim, it does output the echom but the syntax does not work.
I have tried to put this file in multiple folders found during my research on how to add syntax without any success (~/.config/nvim/after/syntax/log.vim, ~/.lvim ).
These are my questions:

How can I add syntax/ftplugin files in a custom folder and tell LunarVim to automatically load them ?
Is my syntax file (this is just for "debugging") valid ?

